# Pandas groupby sort each group values and order dataframe groups based on max of each group

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset containing 3 columns, I’m trying to group them and print each group in sorted fashion (based on highest value in each group). The records in each group also have to be in sorted fashion.

Dataset looks like below.

```
key1,key2,val
b,y,21
c,y,25
c,z,10
b,x,20
b,z,5
c,x,17
a,x,15
a,y,18
a,z,100
```

```
df=pd.read_csv('/tmp/hello.csv')
df['max'] = df.groupby(['key1'])['val'].transform('max')
dff=df.sort_values(['max', 'val'], ascending=False).drop('max', axis=1)
```

I'm applying transform as it works per group basis and then sorting the values.

Above code results in my desired dataframe:

```
a,z,100
a,y,18
a,x,15

c,y,25
c,x,17
c,z,10

b,y,21
b,x,20
b,z,5
```

But, the same code fails for below dataset.

```
key1,key2,val
b,y,10
c,y,10
c,z,10
b,x,2
b,z,2
c,x,2
a,x,2
a,y,2
a,z,2
```

Below is the desired output

```
key1,key2,val
c,y,10
c,z,10
c,x,2

b,y,10
b,x,2
b,z,2

a,x,2
a,y,2
a,z,2
```

Please help me in properly grouping and sorting the dataframe for my scenario.

Comment: Not working with real data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column `key1` to `sort_values` because in second DataFrame are multiple maximum values `10` per groups, so sorting cannot distingush groups:

```
df['max'] = df.groupby(['key1'])['val'].transform('max')
dff=df.sort_values(['max','key1', 'val'], ascending=False).drop('max', axis=1)
print (dff)
  key1 key2  val
8    a    z  100
7    a    y   18
6    a    x   15
1    c    y   25
5    c    x   17
2    c    z   10
0    b    y   21
3    b    x   20
4    b    z    5

df['max'] = df.groupby(['key1'])['val'].transform('max')
dff=df.sort_values(['max','key1', 'val'], ascending=False).drop('max', axis=1)
print (dff)
  key1 key2  val
1    c    y   10
2    c    z   10
5    c    x    2
0    b    y   10
3    b    x    2
4    b    z    2
6    a    x    2
7    a    y    2
8    a    z    2
```

Comment: that works for the 2nd dataset, but fails for the first one. I want to understand why the key1 is include in sorting criteria.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri - hmmm, because duplicates. But I add second solution because in first sample is `key1` sorting descending, but for second sample ascending. So not sure if understand it need this way or not.

Comment: I don't want to sort the key1. The dataset has to be sorted by groups, and each group has to be sorted. key1 and key2 can be any random strings. Groupby key1, group containing the highest val comes as first group.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri - hmmm, I am a bit confused. Because if want sorting by `['max', 'val']` only and `max` is same per multiple groups how is possible separate data per `key1` if not sorting by `key1` ?

Comment: max is not same per multiple groups. I'm applying transform after groupby. So, max will be different for each group.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri - yes, in first sample. But in second is same max `10` per `b` and per `c` groups

Comment: Understood what you're trying to explain. Makes sense. Thanks :)